# NodeMCU sensor values to web page

Tags: nodemcu

I post NodeMCU sensor values to a web page. But how can I pass those values to a database using PHP?

Here is the code to post sensor values to a web page:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "CDS_ARDUINO";
const char* password = "arduinotest@wifi";

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL : ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("Connnection: close");
  client.println();
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");
  client.println("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3\">");
  client.println("<h1>Getting NodeMCU Analog values</h1>");
  int sensorReading = Serial.read();
  client.println("<header>");
  client.println("</header>");
  client.println("<br />");
  client.println("<style>");
  client.println("h1{color: blue;}");
  client.println("</style>");
  client.println("<i>");
  client.print("<h2>");
  client.println("<i>");
  client.print("&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
  client.print(" Analog input value is ");
  client.println("</i>");
  client.print(sensorReading);
  client.print("</h2>");
  client.println("</html>");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Client disconnected");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your question gets closed, since it's only merely related to Arduino, I'd like to post this answer to give you more of an clue on how to set up the system.

1. Connect PHP and the database of your choice.
2. Connect the Arduino to PHP (probably with TCP/IP or HTTP), to send the values to the database.
3. Use PHP (+ webserver) to generate and serve webpages.

Only point 2 is somewhat related to Arduino.SE, so I'll try to give you some "handles" to get started.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient

You can issue a GET request with variables to a webpage using Arduino.
In PHP you can [read out these variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).
And using PHP you can [connect](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) and [send](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) variables to your database.

*You shouldn't connect the Arduino directly to the database, because exposing your database to the world wide web is a security risk.*

After this, it will be relatively easy to generate a page with the contents from your database.